# Java Configuring random number generators in multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, random

I have an application which uses pseudo-random numbers. While I'm testing the application, I want reproducibility, which I arrange by using a seed for the random number generator.  Currently, the RNG is declared inside the class that uses it as a static variable: `private static Random rng = new Random(seed)`. I have a few questions.

1. Given that I want to seed the RNG for reproducibility, does it make sense to declare the variable `static`?
2. I may need to add more different classes which need random numbers. Should I move the RNG to a separate class so I can still use one seed for the whole application? If so, should I use a `static Random` or a singleton object?
3. What happens if I decide to use random numbers in multiple threads? It seems that if I use a strategy like 2., I might still lose predictability, as I can't say for sure the order in which the threads are going to access the RNG. The RNG will still generate the same, predictable sequence of random numbers, but from one run of the program to another, the thread which grabs the first (or nth) random number in the sequence may differ.
4. What this indicates to me is that each thread needs its own RNG in order for results to be reproducible across all runs. Does that mean that each thread needs its own seed? If so, would that guarantee reproducibility, or is there something else I need to do to eliminate the randomness that may be introduced by having multiple threads?
5. Is there a way to generate seeds from a single number which minimizes the correlation between the different RNGs?

In other words, if thread 0 has `Random thread0RNG = new Random(seed)` and thread 1 has `Random thread1RNG = new Random(seed)`, I would only need one seed, but the random numbers in each thread would be highly correlated. I could have two seeds, but then I couldn't associate a run of the program with a single number, passed on the command line, say. Would it be possible and appropriate to say `seed0 = someFunction(seed,0)` and `seed1 = someFunction(seed,1)`?

Comment: As per the SO rules, one question should have one specific problem. Isnt it?

Comment: How about `singleton design pattern` ?

Comment: I think giving an example of _what you want your program to do_ would be useful so that you get answers that actually help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should give each thread its own Random object to avoid unreproducable interleaving due to thread timing.

You can all seed them with the same number, but then they will all get the exact same sequence of numbers. I don't know if that's a problem.

If it is a problem, you can have one "master" Random object to generate the seeds for the other ones. Every time you create a new thread, get the seed from the master. But you have to make sure that you create all the threads (or at least retrieve the seeds) in the same order every time.

Comment: I'm concerned that the random number generators will be too closely correlated if I generated their seeds with the same random number generator. Instead of being identical sequences, the sequences would be shifted by only a few places, no? I guess I should test it ...

Comment: Correllated: yes. But not in a trivial way. Simply shifted by a few places: depends on the algorithm used. You could increase the seeds by a fixed number. That would mix things up.

Comment: I've just played around with 10 Random instances which are seeded by one master instance. I've created sequences of 100 random doubles each. None of all possible pairs of sequences has a correlation coefficient higher than 0.2. Most of them are below 0.05.

Comment: Well, using just the integers 0 to 9 as seed also produces random sequences with low correlation coefficient. Maybe more sophisticated statistical tests are required here.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I've decided to go with the following approach: each thread using random numbers will have a key. A master seed will be supplied to the program. The threads will hash the seed using their key and a cryptographic hash function to obtain the seed for their thread local random number generators. This reduces the correlation between the RNGs, and eliminates the possibility that seeds will depend on the order in which the threads run.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `Random` is thread-safe, so you can safely use it across multiple threads, although due to locking, having one single `Random` instance might result in poor performance. To avoid this, use `ThreadLocalRandom` instead.

But this is no solution, if predicatability is required as in your case. Having one single shared RNG in a concurrent environment will never be predictable. Hence you are right, you'll need **one instance per thread**, and every instance will have to be initialized with a seed.

But if all RNG instances use the same seed, the resulting random sequences will not only be highly correlated, they will be identical! So you'll have to use different seeds for all RNGs

So I suggest to **use a central RNG to generate the seeds** for all other RNGs. But note that this is only predictable, if the order in which the RNGs are seeded is well defined - again this might not be straight forward in a concurrent environment, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RNG for each thread, <strike>for example with [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)</strike>. Multithreading doesn't affect randomness, if each thread have their own generator. The choice of seed is up to you.

Comment: You cannot seed a ThreadLocalRandom. So this will not be reproducible.